# PDF Acro javascript dialog box issue

Tags: javascript, pdf, dialog, acrobat

I am working on creating a custom PDF dialog box and am having an issue getting the values that were entered. I have checked the code and cant find the issue.  When I press accept and display the value that was entered into field1 it says "undefined". Any pointers on where the bug is would be helpful Thanks in advance.

```
 [// Dialog Definition]
var oDlg = {
 field1: "",
 field2: "",
 field3: "",
 field4: "",
// [* initialize: Method that runs when the dialog is created*]
 initialize: function(dialog) {
 var dlgInit = {
 "firstLine":this.field1,
 "secondLine":this.field2,
 "thirdLine":this.field3,
 "forthLine":this.field4,};
 dialog.load(dlgInit);
 },
// [* commit: Method called when OK button is selected*]
 commit: function(dialog) {
  var data = dialog.store();
  this.field1 = data["firstLine"];
  this.field2 = data["secondLine"];
  this.field3 = data["thirdLine"];
  this.field4 = data["forthLine"];
 },
// [* description: Actual dialog box fields *]
 description: {
  name: "Test Dialog",
  elements: [ {
   type: "view",
   elements: [ {
    name: "Additional Information",
    type: "static_text",
   },
   {
    name: "(For Further Credit, Reference of other Information)",
    type: "static_text",
   },
   {
    item_id: "firstLine",
    type: "edit_text",
    char_width: 35
   },
   {
    item_id: "secondLine",
    type: "edit_text",
    char_width: 35
   },
   {
    item_id: "thirdLine",
    type: "edit_text",
    char_width: 35
   },
   {
    item_id: "forthLine",
    type: "edit_text",
    char_width: 35
   },

   {
    type: "ok_cancel",
   },
  ] },
 ] }
};

[// Dialog Activation]
if( "ok" == app.execDialog(oDlg)) { // [* ok_cancel button was pressed with ok *]
app.alert("The value is: "+oDlg.field1,3);
}
```

Comment: My first guess is that there is an issue within the comment section. I have looked through every example I can find and cant find the issue.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.aiim.org/documents/standards/pdf/AcroJS.pdf

Page 99 - Description of item_id:

> "An ItemID for this dialog, which is a unique 4- character string."

Your question is kind of old now, but maybe my answer can help someone else. ;)